# Ctrl + V KeyEventArgs and KeyPressEvent consumed when restricting input to combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a combobox where I need to restrict user input to allow only the following characters:

- Alphanumeric keys (a-Z, 0-9)
- Period, forward slash, comma (./,)

I also need to prevent the Enter/Return key being used within this combobox.

At the moment this is done with a combination of KeyDown and KeyPress events:

```vb
Public Class frm
Dim x As KeyEventArgs
    Private Sub cb_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles cb.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cb_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles cb.KeyPress
        If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) OrElse Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar) Then
                e.Handled = False
            ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." OrElse e.KeyChar = "/" OrElse e.KeyChar = "," Then
                e.Handled = False
            Else
                e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The issue is that this prevents default copy, cut and paste behaviour (CTRL+C, CTRL+X, CTRL+V) from working.

The CTRL key never triggers the KeyPress event, so I don't really understand why it appears to be silently handled and never passed back up to the form, where the default behaviour takes place.

I have `KeyPreview = True` set.

Comment: The CTRL keys (and Enter) are also passed to KeyPress, you don't like them so that's why they don't work.  Set KeyPreview back to False so this code can't mess up other controls.  You don't need KeyDown.  Make the CTRL keys work again by adding If e.KeyChar < " "c Then e.Handled = False.  And suppress the BEEP! produced by the Enter key by adding If e.KeyChar = vbCr Then e.Handled = True.

Comment: I would be remiss when not pointing out that disabling keyboard keys without any feedback is not a great idea.  Drives users pretty nuts, that's an irate support call waiting to happen.  Proper way to do it is accept everything and use the Validating event to point out that you're not happy and why.  ErrorProvider is good to make it subtle yet visible and persistent.

Comment: The ascii code of Ctrl-C Copy id 3, Ctrl-V Paste is 22 and Ctrl-x id (24), see ref http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html